# I want to create a modal to show extra data once fetch API has retrieved the original data

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, fetch

I am trying to make an app which fetches data about EPC (energy efficiency) in homes. I am able to fetch the data using vanilla JS using the search bars either by address or postcode. I have no issue when fetching the data and displaying in the form of cards, however from there i want to be able to click on View details button and fetch the data again so i can include all the data for that specific address or postcode i am after, however when i try and add event listeners to the buttons it adds event listeners after each iteration (i.e first button has one event, second button has two event, third button has three events and so on) im really not sure how to approach this.

`This is my HTML

````
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>EPC App</title>
</head>
<body>



    <div id="heading">
        <img src="./images/epcmanbig.png"  alt="">
        <h1>Check your EPC on your property today !</h1>
    </div>

    <form id="input-container">
        <!-- Address -->
        <div class="address">
            <input id="input-address" placeholder="Search By Address" type="text">
            <button class="btns" id="address-search-btn">Search</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Postcode -->
        <div class="address">
            <input id="input-postcode" placeholder="Search By Postcode" type="text">
            <button class="btns" id="postcode-search-btn">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>


    <div id="output-container">
    </div>

  

    <!-- <button class="btn">Click me</button> -->
    
</body>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```
````

```
This is my Javascript, i have blocked  the API key for security purposes 

// Global Variables
```

```
const outputContainer = document.getElementById('output-container');



const getAddress = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    let address = addressInput.value;

    if(addressInput.value === "") {
        return alert('Please Enter a Address');
    } 



    const apiKey = "Basic ######################################################==";
    const endPoint =`https://epc.opendatacommunities.org/api/v1/non-domestic/search?address=${address}`;
    
    try {
        
       const res = await fetch(endPoint, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            Authorization: apiKey,

        }
       });

       const data = await res.json();
       const rows = data.rows;
    //    Loop through rows array
       rows.forEach(row => {

        const address = row.address;
        const propertyType = row['property-type'];

        console.log(row)

  

        const cards = `  
        
        <div class="cards">
        <div class="card-address">
          <p class="card-title">Address:</p>
          <p class="card-content">${address}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="line"></div>

        <div class="card-property-type">
          <p class="card-title">Property Type:</p>
          <p class="card-content">${propertyType}</p>
        </div>

        <button class="modalBtn">View Details</button>
        
    </div>`


       outputContainer.innerHTML += cards;
       

        // outputContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cards);

               
        let modal = document.querySelectorAll('.modalBtn')

        console.log(modal)

       });


    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    
};


 Get Address Data Modal 



 const getPostcode = async (e) => {

     e.preventDefault();

    let postcode = postcodeInput.value.trim().toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, "");

    if(postcodeInput.value === "") {
         return alert('Please Enter A PostCode');
     } 

     const apiKey = "Basic ################################################## ==";
     const endPoint =`https://epc.opendatacommunities.org/api/v1/domestic/search?postcode=${postcode}`;
    
     try {
        
       const res = await fetch(endPoint, {
         method: 'GET',
        headers: {
             Accept: "application/json",
            Authorization: apiKey,

         }
        });

        const data = await res.json();
        const rows = data.rows;
     //    Loop through rows array
        rows.forEach(row => {

         const address = row.address;
         const buildingEmissions = row['building-emissions'];
         const propertyType = row['property-type'];


         const cards =  `             <div class="cards">
                 <div class="card-address">
                   <h3>Address</h3>
                   <p>${address}</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="line"></div>
                 <div class="card-address">
                   <h3>Building Emissions</h3>
                   <p>${buildingEmissions}</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="line"></div>
                 <div class="card-address">
                   <h3>Property Type</h3>
                   <p>${propertyType}</p>
                 </div>
             </div>
        `;

         outputContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cards);
        });

     } catch (error) {
         console.log(error)     }

 };

 Search Address Btn
const submitAddressBtn = document.getElementById('address-search-btn').addEventListener('click', getAddress);
let addressInput = document.getElementById('input-address')



 Search Postcode Btn
 const submitPostcodeBtn = document.getElementById('postcode-search-btn').addEventListener('click', getPostcode);
 const postcodeInput = document.getElementById('input-postcode');
```

`

```
my CSS
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script&family=Roboto&display=swap');


body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url('./images/energy.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    z-index: -1;
}

body::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 102vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    z-index: -1;
}

#heading {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #fff;
}

#heading img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#output-container::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
  }

#input-container {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border: solid;
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px ;
}

#input-container input {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 60%;
}

#output-container  {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
    width: 80%;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.btns {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.cards {
    border: solid 2px black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;

}
.card-title {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.card-address {
    height: 30%;
}


.card-property-type {
    height: 35%;
}

.card-content {
    font-size: 23px;

}

.line {
    border-bottom: 1px black solid;
    width: 80%;
    border-width: auto;
}

.modalBtn {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the part with the event listeners in your code, but I can see you weren't referring the `.modalBtn` correctly. Let's turn the HTML you append to container, into an HTMLElement. It's recommended and in this case would help us refer to the button inside that element. Check out the function `elemFromString`.

```js
function elemFromString(html) {
  var dummy = document.createElement("div");
  dummy.innerHTML = html.trim();
  var result = dummy.firstChild;
  result.parentNode.removeChild(result)
  return result;
}

const address = "Brazzaville"
const propertyType = "Capital"

// should be called card.
const cards = `  
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card-address">
      <p class="card-title">Address:</p>
      <p class="card-content">${address}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="card-property-type">
      <p class="card-title">Property Type:</p>
      <p class="card-content">${propertyType}</p>
    </div>
    <button class="modalBtn">View Details</button>
  </div>        
`;

var elem = elemFromString(cards);

outputContainer.appendChild(elem);

// and of course you can
elem.querySelector(".modalBtn").addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  
  // fetch then open modal
  alert("modal");
  
})
```

```html
<div id="outputContainer"></div>
```